# Get value of selected image in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div id="select">
   <div class="selected">
    <img src="/abc/image1.png">
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="/abc/image2.png">
   </div>
   <div >
    <img src="/abc/image3.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

I want to get the value of the image when that particular image is selected with `class="selected"`. The `class="selected"` can be with any image. I tried to do it by using two methods

```
var selectImage = $('#select').find('.selected').attr('src');
```

and

```
var selectImage = $('#select').find('.selected').value();
```

But both are not working, first is giving `undefined` value while the second one is giving `""` value. What is wrong in my code?

Comment: You should find attribute from img tag now you searching from selected div. Write your code this style: var selectImage = $('#select > div.selected').find('img').attr('src');

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were close, You need to target `img` child of `selected` element.

```
var str = $('#select .selected img').attr('src');
var fileName = str.split("/").pop()
```

```js
var str = $('#select .selected img').attr('src');
var fileName = str.split("/").pop()

console.log(str);
console.log(fileName);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="select">
   <div class="selected">
    <img src="/abc/image1.png">
   </div>
   <div>
    <img src="/abc/image2.png">
   </div>
   <div >
    <img src="/abc/image3.png">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @satpal its working now. But one more thing by doing attr('src') I am getting value as "/abc/image1.png". If I want to get only "image1.png" then what changes I need to do?

Comment: @user7348570, I have updated answer, with code to get file name

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to get any/all images, regardless of location on the page that have `class="selected"` you can simply do this:

```
var filename = $("img.selected").attr("src").split("/").pop();
```